# Setting URL Parameters with React, React Router, and Firebase (useParams or useRouteMatch)?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-router, react-router-dom

**What I'm Implementing:**

I'm using React (Using Hooks), React Router, and Firebase for a project, and I wanted to use the documentId as the url for when a document is clicked on. The url would look like: https://website.com/view-companies/sdf920k1

**App.js**

```
<Route path="/view-companies/:documentId" component={ViewCompany} />
```

**My Issue:**

I've setup my Route path in my App.js with the :documentId as a parameter, but I'm not sure which hook ([useParams](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/useparams) or [useRouteMatch](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/useroutematch)) to use and if I'm missing something with the setup.

When I query Cloud Firestore and it returns 7 documents, I want to select a document and that documentId is used in the url. I've tried looking for an example of this setup for Firebase on Github, but haven't had any luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click on the document, you can update the url with history like

```
const Component = () => {
   const history = useHistory();

   const handleClick = (documentId) => {
      history.push(`/view-companies/${documentId}`);
   }

   ...
}
```

P.S. If you are using v6 of react-router, you would use useNavigate instead of useHistory

Now in the component you render based on the route you can use `useParams` to get the params

```
const ViewCompany = () => {
   const { documentId } = useParams();
   // do what want with documentId 

   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your. help! I'm using the npm package react-router-dom, but the latest version is 5.1.2. Should I be using react-router?

Comment: No, react-router-dom is fine sand with v5 you can use useHistory how I suggested in the post